# Creating a subscript c in python text

Tags: python, unicode, subscript

I have made some graphs in matplotlib that have a omega with a subscript of b and c. Now i am in the process of creating the buttons to display these plots in tkinter and i was going to use the simple unicode conversion of the subscript chars. However for some reason the unicode subscript alphabet is incomplete and does not contain either a 'b' or 'c'. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: " .. for some reason the unicode subscript alphabet is incomplete ..": The Unicode subscripts were not *meant* to be a generalized "free subscript" feature for any and all character in the entire Unicode set. It was decided to include subscripts with an established meaning only. To change text size, use text markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button with an empty text and an image, which contains the text with subscripts.